# One way background notification from server to client (Django to tell Angular 4 what to happened at the back)

Tags: django, angular

Been looking at this for quite sometime. First, it is not a two way communication. Just the server have to send 1,2 or 3 to the client whenever something happens at the back.

Full Scenario:

Certain employees are allowed to do something that generates XML/JSON files at the back. The rest of the employees make use of those newly created, updated data. The problem is the client might retain a copy even though it has been updated because I get copy of latest generated files when a user logs in or manually checks for any newly generated data.

Now, I want the backend to notify the front-end that there was a change and fetch new content silently.

Current Solution:

My current solution is to check for changes every hour and notify the user to logout-login or manually fetch data with timers like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
Observable.timer(0,3600000).subscribe(() => {
  this.fileConsumerService.checkNew().subscribe(data=> {
    if(data==true){
     alert('New data has been generated. Please click on Update button or relogin')
    }

  })
});
```

While it is working, I am not really comfortable with the solution. Sometimes, the check happens much later after data was pushed, thus employees work on older data. I lowered it to one minute, which is the finest.

What is the way around this please?

Comment: Sounds like you want something in the direction of Websockets. Something like [this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) will do what you want

Comment: I came across Channels actually. But already, the application makes use of Celery + RabbitMQ (removed redis). May be I didn't get it right but doesn't channels change the way my currently stable application? Or it can be plugged in like any other library?